# Android 4.0.1 - XML Rendering Error in EditText. Index:0, Size: 0 - Vew draw failed

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, xml-error

I am having an issue while adding the EditText in my Activity's XML. It's not visible correctly and when I run App it's there but by clicking on it the keyboard does not show I am unable to add any input there. First, I thought I was having this issue only in this Activity but when I tried to add EditText in any other Activity of the project this same thing is happening, but the EditText's that have been added before I have updated to the new version of Android studio 4.0.1 is working fine in XML and also when I run the app - keyboards show up and I can add input, using `compileSdkVersion 29` `minSdkVersion 18` `targetSdkVersion 29` this is my XML. for edit text in this Activity.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/square_border">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/idOrderSummaryPostcode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Enter Postcode"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idOrderSummaryPostcodeAddNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="+ New"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style_round_light_gray_solid"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here's my Activity in `Manifest`

```
<activity
        android:name=".view.Order.Checkout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I have initialized it in the `onCreate` like this

```
private EditText postcode;

postcode = findViewById(R.id.idOrderSummaryPostcode);
```

I am getting this error in my XML Design window.

```
index: 0, size:0
view draw detail(Details)
```

when I click the (Details) here are the details of this error.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:190)
at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:106)
at android.graphics.BaseCanvas_Delegate$1.draw(BaseCanvas_Delegate.java:464)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:697)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:587)
at android.graphics.BaseCanvas_Delegate.nDrawNinePatch(BaseCanvas_Delegate.java:461)
at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawNinePatch(BaseCanvas.java)
at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawPatch(BaseCanvas.java:307)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPatch(Canvas.java:1825)
at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:217)
at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:249)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:87)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper.draw(DrawableWrapper.java:240)
at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:21671)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21435)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1835)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)
at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:404)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:565)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:115)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:142)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:124)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$11(RenderTask.java:894)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

this is the screenshot of my XML the edit text is there but not visible correctly here.

[image]

now, this is the Screenshot of the error below.

[image]

**What I have tried**

1. Clean the project
2. Rebuild the project
3. Close Andorid Studio and open project again.
4. Enable new layout rendering engine from Settings -> Experimental.
5. Disable new layout rendering engine from Settings -> Experimental.
6. Clean Invalid Cashes through `File ---> Invalid Cahes/ Restart`
7. `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`
8. `android:inputType="number"`
9. `android:inputType="text"`
10. infact i have tried all the input types one by one.
11. `android:enabled="true"`
12. `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`
13. `android:focusable="true"`
14. Tried different Emulators.
15. Tried it on physical Devices.
16. i have tried to set it enabled through `JAVA`
17. `postcode.setEnabled(true);`
18. `postcode.setFocusable(true);`

can anyone please help me what can be the issue here ? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

add background property to your edit text.

```
 android:background="@color/colorAccent"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, I have got a solution. Hope it will be work for you.

**Add** `android:background` property inside EditText:

[image]